# can pokeballs capture items such as rice balls

Tags: pokemon

i was re watching episode 25 of the original Pokemon series and while ash threw a ball at manky, manky threw a rice ball back and the rice ball was captured just like a Pokemon but opened when it landed in ash's hands. from what i know, poke balls can capture nothing but Pokemon and it doesn't react to anything but Pokemon. so how does this work?